# Can color-changing leuco dyes be used to indicate when a certain molecule binds to another in a textile fabric?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, everyday-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

Thermochromic leuco dyes change color when the temperature changes. I want to use leuco dyes to make a color-changing fabric. However, instead of using temperature to induce color changes, I want the color to change when a molecule woven into the fabric binds to another molecule, sort of like a lateral flow/pregnancy test.

Can leuco dyes be used to signal when a molecule binds to another and cause a color change in textiles/fabric?

Comment: Okay thank you. What I meant was I want to use the technology of the color changing fabric from leuco dye. However, instead of using temperatures, I wanted to see if a color change could occur if a molecule woven into the fabric binds to another. Sort of like a lateral flow/pregnancy test.

Comment: Ok, I reopened the question. Why limit yourself to leuco dyes though? What have you researched regarding using such dyes as indicators? Would the leuco dye respond directly or indirectly to binding of the molecule?

Comment: I just thought the dye could work like the thermachromic. However, I suppose it could be another type of dye. I haven’t been able to bind any dye that will react when binding takes place in textiles.

Comment: Thermochromic means it responds to temperature. You seem to be looking for something else, something that responds to binding of a particular type of molecule.

Comment: Yes that’s what I’m trying to find.